# This UIObject's element is not set; you may be missing a call to either Composite.initWidget() or UIObject.setElement()

Tags: java, gwt, errai

When running my GWT/Errai app I get this error message:

> 00:00:00.000 [ERROR] Unable to load module entry point class
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container (see associated exception for
>   details) java.lang.RuntimeException: critical error in IOC container
>   bootstrap     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.bootstrapContainer(Container.java:69)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.onModuleLoad(Container.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.AssertionError: This UIObject's element is not set; you may
>   be missing a call to either Composite.initWidget() or
>   UIObject.setElement()     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.getElement(UIObject.java:527)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ui.shared.TemplateUtil.compositeComponentReplace(TemplateUtil.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl$65$1.init(BootstrapperImpl.java:1623)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl$65$1.init(BootstrapperImpl.java:1)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.CreationalContext.resolveAllProxies(CreationalContext.java:351)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.CreationalContext.finish(CreationalContext.java:312)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.bootstrapContainer(Container.java:59)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.onModuleLoad(Container.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

I've already done `mvn clean compile package gwt:run`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably means that you use a `Composite` on which you did not call `initWidget(Widget)`.

Extract of [javadoc for Composite](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8643/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html)

`A type of widget that can **wrap** another widget, hiding the wrapped widget's methods.`

If you don't call `initWidget()`, there is no wrapped widget and it leads to this error message.

It also happens if you `extends UiObject` without calling `setElement()` but this is a rare usecase.

Comment: yeah but looking at the logs the error was thrown within the errai library

Comment: In my case, I had a component inside of that Composite that wasn't calling initWidget(Widget). Simply adding that call within its default constructor solved the problem. I had assumed that super() would call it for me; it didn't - I have my own UiBinder for that component, maybe that's why.

Comment: is possible to check somehow if this initWidget was called before?